# Version control of machine learning model ( about 250 MB)

Tags: git, machine-learning

Our machine learning model produces model of size ~250MB.

Is it good practice to store it in version control ?

I am thinking to store in HDFS and do offsite backup too in NAS.

I also tried to package it as RPM and then deploy RPM on HDFS. But time taken to create rpm , push to nexus is bit issue.

What are best practices around this ?

Thanks

Comment: if it's on hdfs, why do you need a backup?

Comment: Some times things happen :)  by mistake deletions

Answer (score 3):

If your model file can be reproduced deterministically by the code and source you have in git, then it should not be put in git. Traditionally, you put in git all the sources you need to produce your artifacts (binaries, executables, etc...).
Now, if you can't reproduce the file (or the cost of reproducing it is too high) and you want to keep it into your source tree, you may want to have a look at git-annex (https://git-annex.branchable.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Versioning of machine learning model requires tracking following entities,

- Input Snapshot

  1. Code
  2. Environment
  3. Dataset
  4. Input configurations
  5. Input files (input weight file for transfer learning-optional)
- Output Snapshot

  1. Weights
  2. Statistics file (accuracy/other metric representing the weights)
  3. Output Files

These entities combined is a snapshot during the machine learning model building process.

The tool, [Datmo](https://datmo.io/) handles setting up the environment, tracking your progress, sharing work with other community members, and enables deployment of models. It handles datasets/model by saving it to cloud storage systems and not pushing it onto GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @david point - your modeling code should be reproducible and then you do not need to store the model (binary) to git.

Secondly, even if your modeling code is reproducible it usually take a lot of time (and sometimes special computation resources like GPU or 100GB+ memory). It is nice to have a model stored somewhere when you can easily reuse it.

An open source tool http://dataversioncontrol.com solves both of the issues. It works like a make file for ML projects by tracking dependencies and reproducing right part of your ML workflow and it syncs data to S3 or GCP. Models (binaries) stored in clouds could be easily reused.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to store your model in git, you will likely need to use [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/). However, the main downside of storing it in git is that it becomes harder to access in a production environment, and you don't get any of the benefits from version control more broadly (e.g., seeing which lines of code have changed).

The more common practice that I have seen is model artifacts (joblib dumps, ONNX conversions) being stored in a file system, an AWS bucket or similar. The `modelstore` [open source library](https://github.com/operatorai/modelstore) was built to enable this:

```
from modelstore import ModelStore

modelstore = ModelStore.from_aws_s3(os.environ["AWS_BUCKET_NAME"])

modelstore.sklearn.upload("my-model-domain", model=model)
```

As of writing this answer, the library supports nine different machine learning frameworks (full docs are [here](https://modelstore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).